# Convert all the character in a string to "*"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

**Question:**
I have a string say: `"I am a boy"`.

I need a regular expression that convert all the character in the string to `"*"`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post what you have tried please.

Comment: what is the need of regex here?

Comment: i need to replace it using data format string... any idea

Comment: Should it also replace `white spaces`?

Comment: yes u can replace white spaces

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Actually my pupose was that i need a column in the grid showing password. wen we edit that then he column should display the password

Comment: @AnirudhAgarwal - Please tell me that [you're not storing passwords incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)! Please tell me you're not [storing the plain text password in the database](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html)! Please tell me you're using some kind of [secure hashing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html) (and salting)!

Comment: We are saving password in database in encrypted form. we need to display it on the grid as it is in decrypted form....

Comment: @AnirudhAgarwal - If you store passwords in *any* way, shape or form where you can recover the original plain text password (i.e. "decrypt" it), then you are *definately* storing it *wrong*! For the sake of the users of that software, *please* read through the links and try to understand *why* it is wrong and how very vurnerable to attack that system is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can do this without regex:

```
var s = "I am a boy";

var q = new string('*', s.Length);
```

Comment: This will remove the white spaces.

Comment: @Alex what do you mean by kill? It will replace all characters (whitespace is also a character) with `*`

Comment: Fixed my comment. Point being OP may not have wanted that. Although he didn't mention it. So your solution is valid just not regexy :D

Answer (score 2):

Not regex but how about;

```
String input = "I am a boy";
String result = new String('*', input.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace every character including whitespace you can use the following. The dot `.` will match any character (`except newline`).

```
string input  = "I am a boy";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, ".", "*");
// => "**********"
```

If you want to avoid replacing whitespace you can use `\S` which matches any non-white space character.

```
string input  = "I am a boy";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "\\S", "*");
// => "* ** * ***"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since everyone went for \w \s I'll suggest an alternative.

```
var r = new Regex("[A-Za-z0-9]");
var s = r.Replace("I am a boy", "*");
```

This works in a similar way to the other regexes suggested but gives you some more control if say you wanted to leave some characters out or something.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a regular expression expression (pun intended) that matches all whitespace and word characters.

```
var s = "I am a boy";

var regex = new Regex("[\\w\\s]");

var q = regex.Replace(s,"*");
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

assuming OP don't want the `white spaces` to be replaces with `*`

1) This would work: `[a-zA-z0-9]`

```
var str = "I am a boy";
var regex = new Regex(@"[a-zA-z0-9]");
var result = regex.Replace(str,"*");
```

Output: `* ** * ***`
<kbd>[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?37mkk)</kbd>

2) For replacing white spaces also: `[\\w\\s]`

```
var str = "I am a boy";
var regex = new Regex(@"[\w\s]");
var result = regex.Replace(str,"*");
```

Output: `**********`
<kbd>[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?37mkt)</kbd>

OR

```
var str = "I am a boy";
var result = new String('*', str.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

```
Regex.Replace("I AM A BOY", "[\w\\s]", "*")
```

It will give you OP like `* ** * ***`

Comment: Try this with Vb and say

Comment: This question is tagged with c# and .net, I don't know VB. But after quick googeling, I admit probably this regex gives you this output in VB. But you still copied from the other answer and the `\\s` part is not working here (and I guess you don't know what it should be doing), since if it would be working it would have replaced the whitespaces. And replacing additionally backslashes and "s" characters makes no sense.